# Using SQL to identify instances where there is a specified unique grouping/combination

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL, I am trying to identify instances where a unique combination of records is present. For example, I have table ITEMS that lists items sold by a store chain where Store_ID is the location and the Item_ID is the item:

```
Store_ID | Item_ID
01       | A
02       | A
02       | B
02       | C
03       | B
04       | A
04       | B
04       | C
```

...and I want to query the table to identify which store IDs sell all items (the exact combination of 'A', 'B', and 'C'). The result of the table above woud be Store_IDs 02 and 04.

I've tried the following, but it's not returning any rows:

```
SELECT i.Store_ID
FROM Items i
WHERE i.Item_ID = 'A'
AND   i.Item_ID = 'B'
AND   i.Item_ID = 'C'
```

I've also looked at using CONTAINS but can't seem to get it together. I'm sure this is easy, but I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure all of A, B and C are there.

```
SELECT i.Store_ID
FROM Items i
WHERE i.Item_ID in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by i.Store_ID
having count(distinct i.Item_ID) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing to avoid listing the products ...

```
with x101 as (
select cast('01' as varchar2(20)) store_id, cast('A' as varchar2(20)) item_id from dual
union all 
select '02', 'A' from dual
union all 
select '02', 'B' from dual
union all 
select '02', 'C' from dual
union all 
select '03', 'B' from dual
union all 
select '04', 'A' from dual
union all 
select '04', 'B' from dual
union all 
select '04', 'C' from dual
union all 
select '05', 'C' from dual
union all 
select '05', 'B' from dual
union all 
select '06', 'C' from dual
),
x102 as (
SELECT 
   Store_ID, 
   item_id, 
   count(distinct Item_ID) over () as tot_prods,
   count(distinct Item_ID) over (partition by store_id) as store_tot_prods
FROM x101
)
select distinct Store_ID
FROM x102 
where store_tot_prods = tot_prods
;
```